# How do I use the MouseBinding on the entire control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListView` and the goal is to be able to doubleclick an item in order to show some data. And what I have right now works, but only if I click within the green area. If I doubleclick outside the green area (to the right of it) it wont invoke my command. Why is this and what's the proper way of fixing this?

XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkObjects}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                  Command="{Binding DisplayItemCommand}"/>
                </Grid.InputBindings>
                <StackPanel Background="Green">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Port}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MainViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<NetworkObject> NetworkObjects { get; set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    NetworkObjects = new ObservableCollection<NetworkObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        NetworkObjects.Add(new NetworkObject() { Address = $"Address {i}", Port = i });
    }
}
```

NetworkObject

```
public class NetworkObject
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }

    /* CRUD Commands */
    public RelayCommand DisplayItemCommand { get; set; }

    public NetworkObject()
    {
        DisplayItemCommand = new RelayCommand(o => 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wohoo!");
        });
    }

}
```

RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I decided to create a custom `ListViewItem` style and bind the data in there. Not, this removes the hover effect, but that can easily be implemented using triggers.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkObjects}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="2">
                            <Grid.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                  Command="{Binding DisplayItemCommand}"/>
                            </Grid.InputBindings>
                            <StackPanel Background="Green">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Port}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```